# NodeJS forking a bash command using child_process

Tags: node.js, bash

Say I want to run the following bash command: `./someCommand &`. When I use the following Node:

```
var execute = require('child_process').exec;
execute(cmd, function (err, out) {
   // Do stuff
});
```

I can never go inside the callback, and I think the problem is because the process is waiting for `./someCommand` to end, but I've tried to fork it!! What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
execute.('-cs -Some Command-', func(err, res){    
//Do staff
})
```

cs - command shell.

And you can use spawn instead exec.

> https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait, just put your code outside, after `execute`.